# OpsWorks deploy failed after bundle exec rake assets:precompile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, aws-opsworks

I'm trying to deploy an application using AWS OpsWorks with chef, I had have run the deploy in other times and had never failed but this time I got the next message in the log. I run the command bundle 
exec rake assets:precompile] in localhost and everything is alright,
What can be?

```
[2018-03-01T18:50:54+00:00] INFO: Processing execute[cd 
/srv/www/my_project/releases/20180301185045 && RAILS_ENV=production bundle 
exec rake assets:precompile] action run 
(/opt/aws/opsworks/releases/20160504095744_3437-
20160504095744/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/chef-
11.10.4/lib/chef/provider/deploy.rb line 63)

Error executing action 'run' on resource 'execute[cd 
/srv/www/my_project/releases/20180301185045 && RAILS_ENV=production bundle 
exec rake assets:precompile]' 

Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed
------------------------------------
Expected process to exit with [0], but received '137'
---- Begin output of cd /srv/www/my_project/releases/20180301185045 && 
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile ----
STDOUT:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes the instances got out of memory.
Only stop and start the instance where you are doing the deploy.

Answer (score 2):

Agreed that Opsworks will always run into out of memory state during deployment especially on instances (micro/small). SSH to the instance and make swap memory (e.g. 2GB / 4GB) will help to reduce the issue a lot.